# Modeling data where variables are encoded in the rows

Tags: r, machine-learning, modeling, training-data

Suppose you have a training dataset as follows:

```
User_ID Screen_ID Age
1          4       1
2          7       0
3          9       1
3          11      1
.          .       .
.          .       .
.          .       .
```

and I have a test set in the same format as above with no values for Age. I want to use Screens_ID as an independent variable in my model. Do I have to transpose the dataset so that the unique Screen_IDs are columns as below:

```
           Screen ID
User ID       4 7  9  11 . . .
1             1  0  0  0
2             0  1  0  0
3             0  0  1  1
```

or can I use the format in the first table to model this data. The reason I asked is transposing this data will take up too much memory.

Comment: This is a duplicate (that was asked yesterday) ... of a duplicate of a duplicate.

Comment: The big question is: what algorithm do you plan to use?

Comment: I was thing CART or random forests

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to create dummy variables here. You can use [caret](http://127.0.0.1:10206/library/caret/html/dummyVars.html) to do this.

For example, taking a similar data as yours

```
a=as.data.frame(matrix(c(1,2,3,3,4,9,10,11,12,13),ncol=2))
```

which would give

```
>a
  V1 V2
1  1  9
2  2 10
3  3 11
4  3 12
5  4 13
```

using caret's dummyVar method on this

```
library(caret)
to_change=as.factor(a$V2)
to_change=as.data.frame(to_change)
dummies <- dummyVars( ~ ., data = to_change)
dummy_vars=as.data.frame(predict(dummies, newdata = to_change))

pre_final=cbind(V1=a[,1],dummy_vars)
```

Aggregate this over User id or in my case V1 and you get your req. data

```
df= aggregate(.~V1, data=pre_final, sum, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Gives

```
  V1 to_change.9 to_change.10 to_change.11 to_change.12 to_change.13 
1  1           1            0            0            0            0            
2  2           0            1            0            0            0            
3  3           0            0            1            1            0            
4  4           0            0            0            0            1
```